# Tracking an iOS App user

Tags: ios5, uid, uidevice

All,

I would like to collect stats on what users are entering into my apps' search box so I created a web service that phones home with the search string they typed in along with the number of results it returned.

How can I relate these search stats to a specific device? I heard that Apple is going to disallow the access of user device ids:

```
//deprecated
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a third party for your analytics, instead of the web service. Try:

> Flurry.com

is a good one.

Then you could use an app like Stats for Flurry to view your statistics:

[Stats for Flurry](http://flurrystats.devedup.com/)

Yes, Apple has deprecated UDID - but they have provided another method to uniquely identify your users per app. You need to use:

[CFUUIDCreate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFUUIDCreate)

Comment: Thanks,bandejapaisa. I will look at Flurry. What is the accepted method from Apple for identifying users?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/), [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/ios.html) and [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/). If you choose one of those, it will save your efforts. Also, if you want to track bugs, [BugSense](http://bugsense.com/) will help you a lot.